# How to change page number location for first page only

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm writing a style file for a document that requires the page number on the first page to be at the bottom center. On the rest of the pages it needs to be in the upper right hand corner. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: See this answer here: [Change page number location](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1904/2693)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in the stuff for the first page, include the command `\thispagestyle{plain}`.  That will put the page number in the center of the foot for that one page, overriding whatever pagestyle you use for the document as a whole.

Comment: That looks easy enough. Just wondering, though, is there no way to do it within the style file?

Comment: Nevermind, it makes sense now. I just put `\pagestyle{headings}` and `\thispagestyle{plain}` in the class style and it works the way I wanted it to. Thanks.

Comment: @Nate Glenn: Ah, sorry; I'm afraid that I'd misread your question, and didn't notice that you said you were writing a style file.  You figured out how to make it work, though.