# changing page numbering format for different sections

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I would like to have different page number formats for different sections of the document. I notice I can do per page numbering style using `\thispagestyle` ([How to change page number location for first page only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18735/how-to-change-page-number-location-for-first-page-only)) but how can I do the same for a given section rather than a page? I.e., something like the following:

```
\begin{document}
\input{sectionA} %% page numbering style: -A-<page number>-
\input{sectionB} %% page numbering style: -B-<page number>-
\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\thispagestyle` but that doesn't quite work.

Comment: To be honest, i don't understand the question. Are you searching for [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208) Can you show us with a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: There is also \renewcommand{\thepage}{- A -\arabic{page}} and \setcounter{page}{1}

Comment: @john-kormylo I'm basically looking for something like what you mentioned except that I am using fancyhdrs

Comment: I guess the sections are also numbered with letters, so i would suggest `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection--\arabic{page}} along with the aforementioned etcounter` Or define globally that pages are counted sectionwise. This is all independant from `fancyhdr`, but seeing an MWE would be great to provide a solid solution.

Comment: if you want to change just the letter that prefaces the page number, then define the page number field in header definition to use a command for that part of the number field, and change the value of the command just after the relevant sectioning command.  but perhaps you want to start renumbering with 1? an "ascii" example would help.  also be aware that the page heading style takes effect with the first page output after the change is invoked, so if your sections don't start on a new page, then the end of a previous section may get an inappropriate page reference.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and think about solutions when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As has been pointed out before, failing to provide an MWE makes it both difficult for others to help you and difficult for your question to help others. Remember that questions and answers should be of general use - not just of interest to the asker.

Comment: Writing just `\pagestyle` instead of `\thispagestyle` changes the style for the subsequent pages.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you want. It numbers the secions alphabetically, starts every section on a new page and resets the page counter. It also works with `hyperref`.

[image: jrrSectionNumbering]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\section}{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection--\arabic{page}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Wobbling Walrus}
\blindtext[30]
\section{Limbo Lion}
\blindtext[30]
\section{Disco Dogs}
\blindtext[30]
\end{document}
```