# Page numbers- Odd sequence

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am completing my dissertation and my school has a rather odd request.  I'm using the document class "report" so that I have chapters.  The school wants the page number for the first page of each chapter to be in the center of the page and every other page number to be on the top right.  Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: This should be the default. Have you tried?

Comment: Hi-  Specifying nothing seems to make it go to the bottom left on every page

Comment: Oh, so by "center of the page" you mean in "the center of the header"?

Comment: correct.  The instructions from the school are:  "Number the first page of any chapter in the center of the page, one double- space below the last line of text, approximately 5/8 to 3⁄4 inch above the bottom. All other numbers are placed one double-space above the first line of printing and just inside the right margin, that is, approximately 5/8 to 3⁄4 inch from the top and 1 inch from the right edge."

Comment: So, not the "center of the header", but the "center of the footer". Again, this is the default.

Comment: @Werner: But the page number at the right side of the head is for `report` with `oneside` (which is the default) not the default.

Answer (score 3):

You can use, e.g., [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) to change the default header and footer. Here an example using `scrlayer-scrpage`. The default of the plain page style, that is used for the pages with the chapter head, is already with centered number at there page footer. So we need to change only the default of the page header and footer for the non-plain pages:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% automark activates running head
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles% remove the default elements of non-plain pages
\ohead{\pagemark}% page number at outer margin in the head of non-plain pages
\ihead{\headmark}% running head (repeated chapter title) at the inner margin in the head of non-plain pages

\usepackage{mwe}% for dummy text in minimal working examples

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

If you have to change the margins or distances between the head an the text area you can use package [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

For a `fancyhdr` solution see, e.g., [Changing page number location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1905/9057) or [Removing the page number at the bottom of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295845/9057).

Comment: @JasonMcCormack: Hi!  Please note that [Upvoting and accepting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) is the recommended way to show your gratitude to the person(s) who answered your question. :-)